# Static data initialised twice due to typo in import in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a newbie question on TypeScript imports. I tried to make a class which holds some data in a static variable, and the data is lazily initialised in `getInstance()` method.

myStaticClass.ts:

```
class MyData {
  x = 1;
}

export class MyStaticClass {
  private static data: MyData;

  static getInstance() {
    if (MyStaticClass.data == null) {
      console.log('data is null, initialising');
      MyStaticClass.data = new MyData();
    }
    return MyStaticClass.data;
  }
}
```

I imported this class in 2 other classes:

a.ts

```
import { MyStaticClass } from './MyStaticClass';
// NOTE the typo above - uppercase file name
export class A {
  logX() {
    console.log(MyStaticClass.getInstance().x);
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { MyStaticClass } from './myStaticClass';
import { A } from './a';

console.log(MyStaticClass.getInstance().x);
new A().logX();
```

To my surprise, the output of `ts-node index.ts` is

```
data is null, initialising
1
data is null, initialising
1
```

If I correct the import the output is as expected - data is initialised only once.

I also checked that I get one initialisation for one variant of spelling (added 3rd class with another letter in upperCase)

Can anyone explain why this behaviour is in place?
(Additionally, what tools / debug statements I could have used to identify  what is happening?)
Can I force TypeScript to flag this as error?

I am on MacOs, TS 3.6.3, node-ts 8.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While on Windows two differently cased file names always point to the same file, on other platforms they do not. This means that imports with different file names are treated as different modules, this is by design and is not considered an issue ([see here for node discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6000))

The simple solution is to force consistent file casing to be used when importing modules. Typescript does have a compiler option to force this named `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` ([See docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). This option should prevent such issues.

Comment: Checked the links, for me it looks more like wontfix (https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5702#issuecomment-19523491) than 'not a problem'. Thanks anyway, `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` is good enough.